# Construct fixed string by concatenating macro with string

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

I've went through a number of similar questions and almost got it to work, but not quite.

What I have is the standard Macro-Expansion-Stringification-method.

```
#define QUOTEME(M)          #M
#define DOQUOTE(M)          QUOTEME(M)
#define XCONCAT(X, Y)       X##Y
#define CONCAT(X, Y)        XCONCAT(X, Y)
```

Then I have a macro `PREFIX` like this:

```
#define SW_PREFIX    XY2Ar-
```

What I was trying to do was:

```
#define SW_FILE DOQUOTE(CONCAT(SW_PREFIX, update))
```

What this is supposed to output is: `"XY2Ar-update"`
What it outputs on my GCC-type compiler is:

```
error: pasting "-" and "update" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Now, I assume that he's replacing the macro correctly, but apparently doesn't want to append `update` to `XY2Ar-` because of the `-`.

I also tried:

```
#define SW_FILE     DOQUOTE(SW_PREFIX.update)
```

which, once again, almost does what I want, however it outputs
`XY2Ar-.update`, which is not what I want either.

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

```
#define QUOTEME(M)    #M
#define COMPOSE(A, B) QUOTEME(A) #B

#define SW_PREFIX     XY2Ar-
#define SW_FILE       COMPOSE(SW_PREFIX, update)
```

Comment: I did think that I tried something like that before. Error message: `error: pasting ""XY2Ar-"" and ""update"" does not give a valid preprocessing token`. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: You're right, sorry. That was messed up. Check now, I think this works. I think it has to be asymmetric in the two arguments, because one is a bareword and the other needs replacement. [Demo](https://ideone.com/e8GIGN).

Comment: This seems to work, though I think, quite personally, that my solution is a little less...shall we say 'verbose', wouldn't you agree? ;)
I discovered it shortly after I left the comment on your previous solution.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: Yes, absolutely. Feel free to make yours the accepted answer. (That said, your answer also changed the question by allowing `SW_PREFIX` to be a string rather than a bareword, so it's somewhat different situation.)

Comment: Yes, I understand that the situation is a different one, which is why yours remains the accepted one. Otherwise, Jens' answer has a very similar effect to that end.

Answer (score 3):

Your thinking seems too complicated :-) Do not create a single token to stringify. Simply use string concatenation for separate parts.

```
$ cat x.c
#define QUOTEME(M) #M
#define DOQUOTE(M) QUOTEME(M)

#define SW_PREFIX    XY2Ar-
#define SW_FILE  DOQUOTE(SW_PREFIX) QUOTEME(.update)

char *x = SW_FILE;
$ gcc -E x.c
# 1 "x.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x.c"
char *x = "XY2Ar-" ".update";
```

Comment: Yeah, I get that a lot. I also came to the same conclusion a little while ago. Thanks for pointing it out again though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I keep finding myself forgetting the KISS-principle...and it's times like these where it shows.

```
#define SW_PREFIX   "XY2Ar-"
#define SW_FILE     SW_PREFIX"update"
```

These simple lines, no further expansion or anything return the desired output.
As for the reason why it does that:

Since there aren't any `#` in there, it expands `SW_PREFIX` to `"XY2Ar-"` and appends "update" to it, which results in `"XY2Ar-""update"`, which, for the compiler, is the same as `XY2Ar-update`.

Thanks to the guy who erased his answers for reminding me.